# Need to display only the current element of an itertools calculation of a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

When creating a function that subtracts numbers from an element (all user input, and calculates continuously), the compiler only displays all of the elements calculated.

Tried passing the counter as an argument to the subtraction function, but no matter what I try to do with the for loop, I keep receiving index out of bounds errors

```
def number_list(operator_item): #Creates a list of numbers, after calculation, list is returned to main to be assigned to list_of_numbers variable
    number_list = []
    counter = 1
    print("Enter one value at a time and press enter, press = and enter to proceed")
    while number_list != "=": # Calculations are entered until the user types the equal sign, then the answer is returned to main

        try:
            list_value = float(input())
        except ValueError: # Used an exception to confirm sentinel value, this is to maintain accuracy with float number calculations. No error is handled unless "=" is not entered second time
            sentinel_value = input("Press '=' again to complete calculation and copy answer to system clipboard.\n\n") 
            if sentinel_value == "=":
                copy(running_total)
                return running_total
            else:
                print("Invalid entry!")

        number_list.append(list_value) #Each number that is input will be added to list 
        counter += 1

# I have functions for sum and product, but are excluded for relevance
        if operator_item == "-":
            running_total = subtraction(number_list, counter)
            print("Current difference:", running_total)


def subtraction(number_array, number_element):
    total = list(itertools.accumulate(number_array, operator.sub))
    return total
```

Here is my actual results from compiling. I'm just subtracting 5 each time.

Enter one value at a time and press enter, press = and enter to proceed

5 (This is the number I enter on the keyboard)

Current difference: [5.0]

5 (This is the number I enter on the keyboard)

Current difference: [5.0, 0.0]

5 (This is the number I enter on the keyboard)

Current difference: [5.0, 0.0, -5.0]

What I was expecting it to do is this:

Enter one value at a time and press enter, press = and enter to proceed

5 (This is the number I enter on the keyboard)

Current difference: 5.0

5 (This is the number I enter on the keyboard)

Current difference: 0.0

5 (This is the number I enter on the keyboard)

Current difference: -5.0

How can I get it to trim the brackets and all preceding elements?

Comment: What is `number_list`? I assume `counter` is 5.

Comment: what is the use of `number_element`?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Counter is accumulative using a while loop to maintain continuous calculations. 

Number_list is used to store all the numbers and I have functions to calculate the sum, product, and subtraction of the elements. 

Number_element is the current number that the user inputs

Comment: Compiler???????   Heresy!!!

Comment: Python IDLE is what I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour lies within `itertools.accumulate`. Let's take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

> Make an iterator that returns accumulated sums, or accumulated results of other binary functions (specified via the optional func argument).

What does this mean? `accumulate` takes an iterable and a function, and applies this function to the elements of the iterable in a specific order, returning a new iterable containing **all the results**. First it takes the first (two) element(s), then the result of that and the third element, the result of that and the fourth element, and so on - thats what "accumulating calculation" stands for. A simple example:

```
import itertools

def substraction(array):  # adding number_element as an argument is not needed
    total = list(itertools.accumulate(array, lambda x, y: x-y))
    return total

number_array = [5]
print(substraction(number_array))
# prints [5]  (5=5)

number_array.append(5)  # array is now [5, 5]
print(substraction(number_array))
# prints [5, 0]  (5=5, 5-5=0)

number_array.extend([-5, 4, 6])  # array is now [5, 5, -5, 4, 6]
print(substraction(number_array))
# prints [5, 0, 5, 1, -5]  (5=5, 5-5=0, 0-(-5)=5, 5-4=1, 1-6=-5)
```

Now, from what i understand, you are only interested in the last value of that calculation at any point. There is a module named `functools`that has a handy functionality for just that, [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

So again, it will cumulatively substract the numbers from left to right, but only return the current final result as an integer, which is exactly what you want.

```
import functools

def substraction(array):
    total = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, array)  # notice the reversed order of arguments, compared to itertools.accumulate
    return total

number_array = [5]
print(substraction(number_array))
# prints 5 (5=5)

number_array.append(5)
print(substraction(number_array))
# prints 0 ((5)-5=0)

number_array.extend([-5, 4, 6])
print(substraction(number_array))
# prints -5  (((((5)-5)-(-5))-4)-6=-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is in the `substraction` function.

The thing is you can keep it simple:

```
from operator import sub
from functools import reduce           # Python 3.x require this.

def substraction(number_list):         # You don't even need the counter param here.
    return reduce(sub, number_list)    # You don't need itertools neither.
```

Comment: I receive the following error: "NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined"

Comment: What Python version are you using? I've edited for Python 3.x.

Comment: IDLE 3.8 64 bit

Comment: you have to use `functools.reduce`, as reduce is not included in standard python anymore (for python 3.0 and up, see the link in my answer)